# Configuration of Apache2 webserver with JBoss Application server

Tags: iframe, ssl, https, jboss, apache2

I had some queries regarding configuration of Apache web server to jboss app server I am working in a j2ee web based project i am facing some problem in communication between web server(apache2) and app server (jboss).My application uses IFrame .I want to know how to define context root on webserver to map it with app server

Comment: see the link: https://community.jboss.org/thread/81271

Comment: @BMW hey, thanks for your response. At present my configuration for Apache2 in httpd.conf is for index.html which has entry of iframe src= "complete url of my application." now the problem is my webserver has SSL implemented and in iframe src has url of http://www.example.com. so when i am trying to use it message appears for mixed content. Please help me to setup the webserver with SSL implementaion